# NestJs/TypeORM/CloudFoundry - Error when pushing to CloudFoundry

Tags: node.js, typescript, cloud-foundry, nestjs, typeorm

currently I am working on a project where I want to build a NodeJS application which runs on CloudFoundry. The application should provide some data from a database. To realize the requirements I use NestJs and TypeORM.

When I run the application on my local computer everything works fine. But when I try to push the app to Cloud Foundry (using cf push) this error occurs:

```
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     throw err;
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     ^
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error: Cannot find module 'src/allocation/allocation.entity'
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/dist/user/user.entity.js:12:29)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
   2019-10-13T20:21:47.85+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I figured out that the error only occurs if I use TypeORMs Join Decorators (e.g. @OneToMany or @ManyToOne).

This is the source code of "allocation.entity" and "user.entity" (I ommited some properties of the class, to show only the relevant content):

(allocation.entity.ts):

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/user/user.entity';

@Entity()
export class AllocationEntity {

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, user => user.allocations)
  user: UserEntity;
}
```

(user.entity.ts):

```
import { AllocationEntity } from 'src/allocation/allocation.entity';
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class UserEntity {
  @OneToMany(() => AllocationEntity, allocation => allocation.user)
  allocations: AllocationEntity[];
}
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve that problem?

Thx in advance!

f1a2buge

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the import paths:

**Example:**

Wrong:

```
import { AllocationEntity } from 'src/allocation/allocation.entity';
```

Correct:

```
import { AllocationEntity } from '../allocation/allocation.entity';
```

I hope this answer is helpful although you can't see the whole directory structure.